# How to draw a custom transparent box on image according to user's input of size value (of the box) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-graphics

**Problem:** I'm trying to pick an image from the storage. Once the image is selected and shown in the view, I want the user to input a custom size: x, y, height, and width to draw a box on that image.

**What I achieved:**
I already applied a picker to pick the image from the storage.

**What I tried:**
I tried to implement `PencilKit` to draw a box on top of the image.

**Where I'm stuck/ unable to breakthrough**: I'm unable to achieve the drawing of the box as per the user's location input.

It's possible to draw a canvas but taking a custom revolution/location/path of the box
what I want:
As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0UXP.png) the rectangle box visible is according to the user's input of x and y points and length and width from origin of the picture.

Below is the static code that I applied to draw a box but unable to buid it dynamically:

```
struct Rect: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            let width: CGFloat = 30
            let height: CGFloat = 30
            // 1
            path.move(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: 0 * width,
                    y: 0 * height
                )
            )
            // 2
            path.addLine(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x:  1 * width,
                    y: 0 * height)
            )
            // 3
            path.addLine(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: 1 * width,
                    y: 1 * height)
                
                
            )
            
            path.addLine(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: 0 * width,
                    y: 1 * height)
                
                
            )
            
            
            
            // 4
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If it’s only drawing a rectangle that you’re after, wouldn’t it be easier to create the rectangle & let the user position it while also giving them the freedom of resizing? This could be easily achieved using `DragGesture` & `MagnificationGesture`.

Comment: For time being i'm okay to implement a certain shape(square/rectangle) through gesture on top of picture. but as the app will be dealing with creating small /micro scale of such boxes and have different purpose altogether rather than cropping/editing image concept.
So this requirement is different. I had the same thing in mind that using crop feature will be easy/ pencil kit .